# How to change number of layers of a raster brick

Tags: r, image, layer, sample, databricks

When I load a tiff image in R as raster brick then I have the expected number of pixels (number rows and columns) when I check afterwards the details of the image. But I expect 44 layers. I think I can change the number of layers with the nlayers function. Unfortunately, this does not work. The number of layers remain at 4.

```
sample_brick = brick("file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff", nlayers = 44)
```

Can someone help me how to adapt the number of layers?

Here you can find a example tiff image.

https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff

Comment: Thanks for your question. It's very hard to assess your problem without a reproducible example. Can you provide a link to a small tif file that can be used to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `brick` function creates a `RasterBrick` that has all the layers that are in your file.
Your expectation is probably wrong.

You cannot add imaginary layers when creating an object from file.

Comment: Okay I see that. I have all data from all the layers in a list file. But unfortunately I cannot implement a list in the brick function. Or is this somehow possible?

Comment: You can do `lapply(filenames, brick)`, but you may prefer `stack(filenames` instead